# Detect resulting executable from Vim

Tags: vim, cmake

I have a multi-file project and I use Cmake build system. I have mapped `:make` to a key as I need to compile it very often. The problem is that I need to run the resulting executable just as often. However typing `:!./variable_program_name` is very tedious.

Is there any way to detect/get the resulting executable file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone viewing this..
I had the same need and decided to solve it with a vim script/plugin.
[vim-target](https://github.com/raspine/vim-target)

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way to do this is via a separate target in the Makefile, so that for example `:make` just triggers the build, and `:make run` triggers (build and) run of the executable. After all, the Makefile knows best what it's building, so the decision how to run the build artifacts (maybe also with passed arguments) is best delegated to it.

#### Alternative

To "return" the executable from the Makefile, the `:make` output is parsed and populates the *quickfix list*. You could define a custom mapping (for the `qf` filetype, which is set for such windows) that parses the executable name from the current quickfix line, or even use `getqflist()` to parse the entire output. That requires that your Makefile prints out the executable name (and path) in a way that can be detected.

#### Alternative

If you can't even reliably get the executable name from the output, but know the directory where the executable is generated in, you can create a list of files (with `glob()`) before running `:make`, then after it again, and compare the two lists to get the executable name. If you don't want to remove the previous executable from within Vim, a filetime check (`getftime()`) could help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'd prefer not to pollute the makefile/cmakelists

Comment: I would find such a target also helpful from outside Vim. Anyway, I thought of another (more desperate) alternative; see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ingo Karkat's ideas, this script should do the trick (I am not good with vimscript so I wrote it in bash)

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script tries to build the project using Makefile, and if that fails
# it tries to generate the Makefile with Cmake.
# Then it finds the latest executable file and runs it

# Remember to manually run cmake after changing CMakeLists.txt as a new 
# Makefile will not be automatically regenerated

if [[ -e "Makefile" ]] || [[ -e "makefile" ]]; then
    make
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error when running make"
        exit
    fi
else
    if [[ -e "CMakeLists.txt" ]]; then
        cmake .
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
            echo "Error when running cmake"
            exit
        fi
        make
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
            echo "Error when running make"
            exit
        fi
    else
        echo "CMakeLists.txt doesn't exist"
        exit
    fi
fi

# Find latest executable file
unset latest
for file in "${1:-.}"/*
do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        latest=${latest-$file}
        find "$file" -executable -prune -newer "$latest" | read -r dummy && latest=$file
    fi
done

if [[ -x "$latest" ]]; then
    ./$latest
else
    echo "Latest file $latest is not executable"
fi
```

Just put this script in your `$PATH` and map a key to execute it.